# How to show inner axes all around a GridSpace/GridMatrix in Holoviews?

Tags: python, plot, holoviews

How to show the inner axes of a Holoviews GridSpace/GridMatrix all around the plot? `shared_xaxis=True` and `shared_yaxis=True` only show the inner axes at the left and bottom. See the sample code and picture below.

```
%%opts GridSpace [shared_xaxis=True shared_yaxis=True xaxis=None yaxis=None]

def sine_curve(phase, freq):
    xvals = [0.1* i for i in range(100)]
    return hv.Curve((xvals, [np.sin(phase+freq*x) for x in xvals]))

phases      = [0, np.pi/2, np.pi, 3*np.pi/2]
frequencies = [0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25]
curve_dict_2D = {(p,f):sine_curve(p,f) for p in phases for f in frequencies}

hv.GridSpace(curve_dict_2D, kdims=['phase', 'frequency'])
```

[Picture of sample output: Left: actual; Right: desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3ijN.png)

Comment: This is not currently possible (easily) as far as I know, you could file a feature request though. To make it work right now you'd have to index each object along the top/right edges and use ``.options(xaxis='top')`` and ``.options(yaxis='right')`` to make it work.

Comment: @philippjfr While that technically adds the axes, the plots along the top and right edges are squeezed to accommodate the added axes [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzNE6.png). I will file a feature request.